# What direction would this photon go?

Tags: particle-physics, photons, momentum, antimatter

Say a matter-antimatter pair of particles annihilates linearly (from a reference frame where the sum of the momenta is zero) to create a photon.

Wouldn't momentum conservation prevent the photon from having any direction?

If not, what direction would the photon go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, there's no direction for the photon to go.

This is not a contradiction, but really a proof that the proposed process can't happen; a particle and its antiparticle can't annihilate into just *one* photon. However, more than one photon is perfectly fine. For example, two can come out back to back.